# sum of xors of subsets of size k from given array

Tags: sum, xor

for above problem, I found all the subsets of size k and calculated their xors using below method:

```
void getSum(long arr[], long data[], int start, int end, int index, int r, long currXOR)
{   
    if (index == r)
    {
        sum = (sum%mod + currXOR%mod)%mod;
        return;
    }

    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        currXOR = currXOR ^ arr[i];    //consider current element for xor
         getSum(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r, currXOR);
         currXOR = currXOR ^ arr[i];   //exclude current element from xor
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't pass the time complexity constrain for some test cases. Since it was asked online coding round, test cases are unknown.

Can you help me solve the problem in more efficient way?